# Install pipx on Windows - globally or within a virtual environment?

Tags: python, brownie

Should I install pipx globally or can I install it in an already existing virtual environment?

What does `python3 -m pipx ensurepath` do specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`python3`: This is telling your terminal to use `python3`

`-m`: Use a specific python module

`pipx`: The pipx python module

`ensurepath`: ensures that the application directory is on your $PATH. You may need to restart your terminal for this update to take effect.

You'll want to install this globally. `pipx` allows you to run packages in their own virtual environment. This is good for working with `brownie` because `brownie` will always use the exact packages that `brownie` needs to use, and will be isolated from whatever packages you install globally otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, Patrick! I'm actually watching your solidity tutorial and trying to replicate the steps. Currently stuck at the Brownie part though. When installing Brownie should I install it also globally or in my virtual environment?

Comment: Yes. Globally. Please use pipx. It'll make your life 10x easier.